# serverless webpack config, manually add directory

Tags: node.js, webpack, sequelize.js, serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

I have the following code I am running that is failing to work because it can not find the models folder when I upload to amazon.

```
exports.setModels = function(connection,modelPath){
  //Import all the known models for the project.

  //Proof of Stage being set.
  console.log("stage for models="+stage);

  const fs = require('fs');
  const dir = modelPath;

  var models = {};

  //@JA - Wait until this function finishes ~ hence readdirSync vs regular readdir which is async
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
    console.log("file="+file);
    //Split the .js part of the filename
    var arr = file.split(".");
    var name = arr[0].toLowerCase();
    //Create a modle object using the filename as the reference without the .js pointing to a created sequelize instance of the file.

    var modelPath = "../models/"+file; //default assumes same directory that was used to scan.
    if(process.env.DOMAIN_NAME){ //If this enviroment variable is detected then change the modelPath.
      modelPath = "../../../../models/"+file;
    }
    models[name] = connection.import(modelPath);
  })
  return models;
}
```

After investigating the issue, I found out its because the models folder is not being packaged by the serverless webpack plugin.

I found out recently how to force certain packages to upload using this code in my serverless file.

```
webpackIncludeModules:
    forceInclude:
      - mysql
      - mysql2
```

This will only seem to include packages however, and when I tried to reference the models folder to automatically include all my sequelize models I got an error saying it was not a package, which of course makes sense.

This does leave me with the question of **how I can get it to package the models directory without manually doing a require for each model**.  I wrote a dynamic function to get them at runtime and import it to sequelize.

Information on the plugin is here (https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack), I looked through it all but can't seem to find the answer.

The output of packaging with serverless looks like this, missing the models folder with all my sequelize models.

[image]

My main directory before doing webpack looks like this.

[image]

Here is my webpack.config.js as well.

```
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: For now to move forward, I've manually created references to the model and loaded via import's secondary option with sequelize after loading from the files.  This is the only workaround I got for now.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) to include the models instead of referencing.

```
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    target: "node",
    // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
    // we exclude all node dependencies
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                include: __dirname,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugin: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(filesToCopy, {})
    ]
};
```

make sure you import the models from the right folder since you are importing from relative path. This might change if you're bundle is in a different folder.